# Why does sed -e 's/[ +-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]*//g' not work?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to remove all floating point numbers from a string using sed. Therefore I use

```
sed -e 's/[ +-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]*//g'
```

But it does not work:

```
echo 1.2456 | sed -e 's/[ +-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]*//g'
```

gives `1.2456`. If I remove the `[ +-]?` block, it works for positive numbers.

Comment: I only accept them, if they are solved. The open ones are not solved as I need them.

Comment: Note that your regex also removes lone dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` sign is an extended regex character. `sed` needs to be called with the `-r` option to enable the extended expressions.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the question mark:

```
echo 1.2456 | sed -e 's/[ +-]\?[0-9]*\.[0-9]*//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

escape `?`
or `sed -r`

then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This version is more comparable. ? doesn't work on all systems, and + can mean repeat once or more.

```
echo 1.2456 | sed -e 's/[ \+\-]*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*//g'
```